# Cant install Angular on MacOS

Tags: angular, macos, terminal, installation

I can't install the framework Angular on my Mac.

`Mac version:` `macOS Mojave version 10.14.6`

The terminal suggest I should be using an admin account to make this installation work.

This is what I have been using to the terminal for the install:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

This is the error displayed, copying and pasting the code is not comprehensive so instead I made the snapshot.

[image: Error]
Please help!

Comment: have you tried sudo?

Comment: You just refer following link it will help you.
https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/setup-angular-mac

Comment: that was one of the websites that i followed it's guide but did not worked for me, yes i have nodejs installed previously.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is well known on macOS machines, and is linked to how your OS protects certain directories. Here is the procedure recommended in the NPM docs:

- Back up your computer.
- On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations: `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
- Configure npm to use the new directory path: `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
- In your preferred text editor, open or create a `~/.profile` file and add this line:
  `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
- On the command line, update your system variables: `source ~/.profile`

Alternatively, you can install NodeJS and NPM using a version manager like `nvm`. With both of these methods, you are simply creating and defining a new directory where all of your NPM stuff will be installed. This prevents you from having to use `sudo` to install packages.

Comment: This is the solution I use on every linux machine and works like a charm

Comment: thank you @Will Alexander will give this a try in a few hours!

Comment: On my text editor, Visual Studio Code i tried to create a profile by entering ```~/.profile``` into the terminal but the permission was denied

Comment: Something "strange" happened as i was able to install the framework via the terminal on Visual Studio Code. This, after entering both ```mkdir ~/.npm-global```and ```npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'``` (Mac Terminal) And once in the VSC terminal i used ```sudo npm install -g @angular/cli```

Comment: Another thing, i tried to make a new app via the VSC terminal by using ```ng new my-app``` and it did not worked, but on the Mac Terminal it seems it has been. So im unsure if the installation needs something else. Why?

Comment: Another comment, the problem seems to be around the fact that my permit is denied to making folders, I get ```EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/my-app'```

Comment: Is your computer account an Admin one? Where are you trying to create directories?

Comment: Yes it's basically the only account I use all the time. This particular directory ```.npm-global``` which is hidden is under my username so the path is: USER/.npm-global, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in as a super user.

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install angular using brew. Use [this](https://brew.sh) link to find more about how to install Brew on your macOS, and about Angular while using brew the details are [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/angular-cli). You only need to run `brew install angular-cli` I think on the terminal, so I hope that works out for anyone else having issues regarding this frameworks installation.